# Fedora slow boot time

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, performance

I recently removed Windows from my machine because I would like to adopt Linux as my main OS, specifically Fedora. Following are my machine specs:

[image]

The system works pretty well, but the problem is that I noticed a long system boot tim and a long delay between entering my password and jumping to the dekstop.
This is the output from `systemd-analyze blame`:

[image]

There's anything I can do to speed up the boot time? Considering the machine hardware I think that ~50 seconds boot time is too high. The only thing I did to try to solve the problem myself is to install NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 0):

On that run, akmods seems to be compiling modules.  Does that keep happening on each boot?  Anyhow, see [Manually invoking akmods-nvidia to build for a new kernel : Fedora](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/12yq680/manually_invoking_akmodsnvidia_to_build_for_a_new/).  Probably, `dracut -f --regenerate-all` will help; otherwise, checkout the other suggestions.

Comment: Yes, this happens on each boot. I tried the command you suggested but unfortunately it didn't do the job. Same for the other commands on the thread you shared.